# custom button is adding product to cart

Tags: magento-1.9

we have custom button "save design1" in [product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) , everytime when we click on that, its adding product to cart, but we are using only below code for that :

```
<button >save design1</button>
```

how to find what code is reason for adding the product to cart....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope your  button is inside the main form scope in which your add cart button lies . That's why when you press this custom button whole form  is submitted (treated as add to cart functionality).

Kindly check your button position.

Comment: @BabyinMagento  I want to make same functionality for my client . Can you suggest me how you made that custom " add image" and   "add text" options.    I can raise a new question

Comment: actually we bought an extension , if you search in google regarding `product personalization` extension, you will get lot of extensions, try and choose the best one.....

Comment: thats better, by default magento support custom options, you can extend that features....